# Using Basic auth with OAuth2 and JHipster

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jhipster

we use jhipster to generate gateway and microservices with OAuth2 authentication, and that works fine with a JHipster Registry and a Keycloak server. But we have a microservice that will be called from an external service, and this service use basic authentication.

So, on the gateway, we need to send login and pasword from basic auth to keycloak server, and use access token to call our service. I get access token by adding filter in MicroserviceSecurityConfiguration class :

```
http.addFilterBefore(basicAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

And here a extract of filter method :

```
ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails details = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
details.setAccessTokenUri("http://keycloakserver/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/token");
details.setGrantType("password");
details.setClientId("clientId");
details.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);
details.setUsername(login);
details.setPassword(password);

AccessTokenRequest tokenRequest = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();
ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider provider = new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider();

OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = provider.obtainAccessToken(details, tokenRequest);
```

I guess I have to store this token in tokenStore, but I don't know how. So my questions are how use this token, and does the the way I get it is correct ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I Have same problem with you in my production system, then I changed Authentication server to JHipster UAA server, and problem is resolved.

I think you are using first kind now:

OAuth 2.0 / OIDC Authentication: 
this uses an OpenID Connect server, like Keycloak or Okta, which handles authentication outside of the application.

Authentication with JHipster UAA server: 
this uses a JHipster UAA server that must be generated separately, and which is an OAuth2 server that handles authentication outside of the application.

Answer (score 0):

After some tests and trial and error, I managed to do that I want.

First, I created a BasicAuthenticationFilter class :

```
@Configuration
public class BasicAuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String GRANT_TYPE = "password";
    private static final String BASIC_AUTH_HEADER = "Authorization";
    private static final String BASIC_PREFIX = "Basic ";

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri}")
    private String accessTokenUri;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.client-id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    private ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider provider;

    public BasicAuthenticationFilter( ) {
        provider = new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String header = null;
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            header = httpRequest.getHeader(BASIC_AUTH_HEADER);
            if (header != null && header.startsWith(BASIC_PREFIX)) {
                String base64 = header.substring(BASIC_PREFIX.length());
                String loginPassword = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64.getBytes()));
                String[] split = loginPassword.split(":");
                String login = split[0];
                String password = split[1];
                authenticate(httpRequest, login, password);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private void authenticate(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, String login, String password) {
        ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails details = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
        details.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
        details.setGrantType(GRANT_TYPE);
        details.setClientId(clientId);
        details.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.query);
        details.setUsername(login);
        details.setPassword(password);

        DefaultAccessTokenRequest tokenRequest = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();
        tokenRequest.setCurrentUri(httpRequest.getRequestURI());
        try {
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = provider.obtainAccessToken(details, tokenRequest);
            OAuth2Authentication oauth2Authentication = tokenStore.readAuthentication(accessToken);
            AccessTokenDetails accessTokenDetail = new AccessTokenDetails(accessToken.getValue());
            oauth2Authentication.setDetails(accessTokenDetail);
            SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
            context.setAuthentication(oauth2Authentication);
        } catch (OAuth2AccessDeniedException e) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Wrong credentials !");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    public static class AccessTokenDetails {

        private static final String DEFAULT_TOKEN_TYPE = "bearer";

        public final String tokenType;
        public final String tokenValue;

        public AccessTokenDetails(String tokenValue) {
            this(DEFAULT_TOKEN_TYPE, tokenValue);
        }

        public AccessTokenDetails(String tokenType, String tokenValue) {
            this.tokenType = tokenType;
            this.tokenValue = tokenValue;
        }
    }

}
```

This filter check if there are basic authentication, and if yes, authenticate user. The authentication details are stored in internal class AccessTokenDetails. So, the token can be read in AuthorizationHeaderUtil :

```
public class AuthorizationHeaderUtil {


    public static String getAuthorizationHeader() {
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
        Object details = authentication.getDetails();
        String tokenType = "";
        String tokenValue = "";
        if (details instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) {
            OAuth2AuthenticationDetails oauth2Details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) details;
            tokenType = oauth2Details.getTokenType();
            tokenValue = oauth2Details.getTokenValue();
        } else if (details instanceof AccessTokenDetails) {
            AccessTokenDetails accessTokenDetails = (AccessTokenDetails) details;
            tokenType = accessTokenDetails.tokenType;
            tokenValue = accessTokenDetails.tokenValue;
        }
        return String.format("%s %s", tokenType, tokenValue);
    }
}
```

This class has been generated by JHipster, I add a check for the two authentication detail class I use.

I hope that will be useful.

Denis